# I/O Performance in Linux

Tags: linux, file, io

File A in a directory which have 10000 files, and file B in a directory which have 10 files, Would read/write file A slower than file B?
Would it be affected by different journaling file system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Browsing the directory and *opening* a file will be slower (whether or not that's noticeable in practice depends on the filesystem). Input/output on the file is exactly the same.

**EDIT:**
To clarify, the "file" in the directory is not *really* the file, but a *link* ("hard link", as opposed to symbolic link), which is merely a kind of name with some metadata, but otherwise unrelated to what you'd consider "the file". That's also the historical reason why deleting a file is done via the `unlink` syscall, not via a hypothetical `deletefile` call. `unlink` removes the link, and if that was the last link (but only then!), the file.

It is perfectly legal for one file to have a hundred links in different directories, and it is perfectly legal to open a file and then move it to a different place or even unlink it (while it remains open!). It does not affect your ability to read/write on the file descriptor in any way, even when a file (to your knowledge) does not even exist any more.

Comment: Generally applications that handle massive amounts of files on the disk (Squid) will create a hierarchy based on the file name to split them up across directories.

Comment: @Geoffrey Will that affect the time to find the file to open it and/or the I/O performance while reading/writing? Does it make sense to create this kind of structure based on the used file system? Yes, you can read these questions as slightly tongue in cheek.

Comment: @HonkeyTonk = If your dealing with heaps of files, you should do this, its not that hard, eg... just hash the filename with md5/crc32 or something, and then use the first 2/3 sets of hex characters for 2/3 levels. Eg: "abc.txt" becomes "56b6f095", so make the path "/56/b6/f0/abc.txt", or deeper if you want. You could even use the rest of the hash as the filename instead.

Answer (score 1):

In general, once a file has been opened and you have a handle to it, the performance of accessing that file will be the same no matter how many other files are in the same directory. You *may* be able to detect a small difference in the time it takes to open the file, as the OS will have to search for the file name in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Journaling aims to reduce the recover time from file system crashes, IMHO, it will not affect the read/write speed of files. [Journaling ext2](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/journal-design.pdf)